# Plotly color and symbol combination in Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to plot using plotly my data. It works fine until when I plot only using the color attribute:

Plot here
[image: Plot here]

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly as plt
fig = px.scatter(df, x="Sample", y="NB_total",  color = "Method")
fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers', marker_line_width=2, marker_size=20)
fig.show()
```

But whenever I add `symbol = "Treatment"` it does separate my data in 3 different datasets.

Not working plot here
[image: Not working plot here]

I would like to have the same plot as the first but with different shape for every "Treatment".

Thanks a lot !!

PS: please don't bother about the legend, I just modified it for the post.

**EDIT 1**: Here is a sample of my data

```
Sample  NB_total    Method  Treatment
S1      17992586    M1      T1
S1      16100774    M2      T1
S1      22710941    M3      T1
S2      19033904    M1      T2
S2      22978354    M2      T2
S2      17014336    M3      T2
S3      22987118    M1      T1
S3      19806864    M2      T1
S3      14489847    M3      T1
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data which represents *your* dataset.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post and  did add a subset of my data

Comment: You mentioned "but with different shape for every "Treatment"." But currently every treatment has different shape e.g., T1 is a circle, T2 is a diamond and T3 is a square.

Comment: I think you need to explain more your desire output, please.

Answer (score 0):

- this really comes down to how your data is structured.  Each *Sample* has only one *Treatment*.  **Plotly Express** **color** and **symbol** work off these are full dimensions of data.  Not like your case where *Treatment* is not a dimension but an attribute
- given want to visualise *Treatment* attribute, this can be achieved by building figure with dimensions (*Method*, *Sample*, *NB_total*).  **marker_symbol** can be an array/list.  Next step is to define it as a list based on values of *Treatment*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import itertools

# simulate data
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        [[f"S{s}", f"T{t}"] for s, t in zip(range(1, 10), np.random.randint(1, 4, 10))],
        columns=["Sample", "Treatment"],
    )
    .merge(pd.DataFrame({"Method": ["M" + str(n) for n in range(1, 4)]}), how="cross")
    .pipe(
        lambda d: d.assign(
            NB_total=np.random.randint(14 * 10 ** 7, 22 * 10 ** 7, len(d))
        )
    )
)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="Sample", y="NB_total", color="Method").update_traces(
    mode="lines+markers", marker_line_width=2, marker_size=20
)

# build dict that maps as treatment to a symbol
symbols = ["circle","diamond","square"]
symbol_map = {t:s for t, s in zip(np.sort(df["Treatment"].unique()), symbols)}

# for each trace update marker symbol to list of symbols that correspond to treatment
for t, s in zip(fig.data, df.groupby("Method")["Treatment"].agg(lambda x: [symbol_map[v] for v in x])):
    t.update(marker_symbol=s)


fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also wanting to keep combinations of color (according to var1) and symbol (var2) in a plotly express graph object, I needed a slighly different solution. Using the standard syntax did not respect the legendgroups (combinations of var1 and var2 values) already created in the graph object using `color='var1'` and `symbol='var2'`. Instead all legendgroups got the same list of three symbols.

```py
symbols=['cross','circle-open','diamond-open'] # https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter3d/#scatter3d-marker-symbol
symbol_map = {value:symbol for value, symbol in zip(set(figure_df['var2']), symbols)} # map 3 unique values in var1 to symbols

for data in figure.data:
    var2_value = indData['legendgroup'][-3:] # extract string values of length 3 in var2
    symbol = symbol_map.get(var2_value)
    indData['marker']['symbol'] = symbol
```