# How to show only color coding in the legend of my plotly scatterplot in python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm plotting some PCAs with plotly.express scatterplot function, and coding the samples by region (color) and breed (symbol). When I plot it, the legend show me all 67 different breeds in their combinations of symbols and colors. Is there a way to show only the color categories instead?

My data looks like this:

|  | PC1 | PC2 | PC3 | Breed | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | value | value | value | breed1 | Region1 |
| Sample2 | value | value | value | breed2 | Region1 |
| Sample3 | value | value | value | breed3 | Region2 |
| Sample4 | value | value | value | breed1 | Region1 |

Right now my code is just the basic command:

```
fig=px.scatter(pca, x="PC2",y="PC1", color="Region", symbol="Breed", labels={
    "PC2":"PC2-{}%".format(eigen[1]),
    "PC1":"PC1-{}%".format(eigen[0])
})

fig.layout.update(showlegend=True)
fig['layout']['height'] = 800
fig['layout']['width'] = 800
fig.show()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, try to edit your data in the question, it is not well formatted.

Comment: color='Pop' meaning 'region'='Pop'?

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed the name so it was easier to understand, but forgot to update the code.

Comment: So, you only need color in legend and remove the symbols, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. Right now the legend is massive and totally uninformative. I would like to display only the names of the regions with their associated color, which is the most interesting thing on the plot.

Comment: your sample data really doesn't show this issue.  see this answer on how to split colors and symbols https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71487054/plotly-color-and-symbol-combination-in-python/71493912#71493912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these lines:

```
region_lst = []

for trace in fig["data"]:
    trace["name"] = trace["name"].split(",")[0]
    
    if trace["name"] not in region_lst and trace["marker"]['symbol'] == 'circle':
        trace["showlegend"] = True
        region_lst.append(trace["name"])
    else:
        trace["showlegend"] = False
        
fig.update_layout(legend_title = "region")  
fig.show()
```

Before adding the lines of code:
[image]

After adding the code:
[image]

I used this dataframe:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.medals_long()
fig = px.scatter(df, y="nation", x="count", color="medal", symbol="count")
```

Answer (score 0):

- specifying **color** and **symbol** results in legend being combination of values in respective columns
- to have legend only be values in one column, change to use just **color**
- to represent second column as symbols, change each trace to use a list of symbols
- have synthesized data based on your description

#### full code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.validators.scatter.marker import SymbolValidator

eigen = [0.5, 0.7]

# simulate data
n = 1000
pca = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{f"PC{c}": np.random.uniform(1, 5, n) for c in range(1, 4, 1)},
        **{
            "Breed": np.random.choice([f"breed{x}" for x in range(67)], n),
            "Region": np.random.choice([f"Region{x}" for x in range(10)], n),
        },
    }
)

# just color by Region
fig = px.scatter(
    pca,
    x="PC2",
    y="PC1",
    color="Region",
    labels={"PC2": "PC2-{}%".format(eigen[1]), "PC1": "PC1-{}%".format(eigen[0])},
)

# build dict that maps as Breed to a symbol
symbol_map = {
    t: s for t, s in zip(np.sort(pca["Breed"].unique()), SymbolValidator().values[2::3])
}

# for each trace update marker symbol to list of symbols that correspond to Breed
for t, s in zip(
    fig.data, pca.groupby("Region")["Breed"].agg(lambda x: [symbol_map[v] for v in x])
):
    t.update(marker_symbol=s)


fig
```

[image]